# How to downcast an object of type Object to an array?

Tags: java

Suppose we have the following, how can I downcast Object o to an array? That is because in my code I am using an object pointer to point to a certain object at a certain time each objects of different types.

```
Object obj = new int[4];
```

Comment: I meant o @Progman, I will edit it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you want to cast to which type? Where do you need the cast? Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and describe in detail what you want to do.

Comment: There is no general "array" type in Java. If it's an array of reference types (e.g. `String[]`, `Integer[]` etc), you can cast to `Object[]`; if it's an array of primitives (e.g. `int[]`, `double[]`), there is no common type other than `Object` or `Serializable`, neither of which is "array-like".

Comment: I agree that there is no array type in java. On the other hand, java treats arrays as objects. @AndyTurner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object o = new int[4];
int[] array = (int[]) o;
```